# How to rotate BufferedImage as object itself

Tags: java, eclipse, frame-rate

I have trouble with performance when I am rotating every image, when drawing it FPS has dropped from 1400 to 6. Can I rotate BufferedImage object just after creating it, so the calculation happens only once?

There is my Grid Control class: (Drawing class, problem method is drawRotated())

```
package cs.meowxiik.universes.graphics;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.util.Observer;

import cs.meowxiik.universes.map.Map;
import cs.meowxiik.universes.map.Tile;

public class GridControl {

    int width;
    int height;
    int xcells;
    int ycells;
    int cellWidth;
    int cellHeight;

    int maxZoom = 80;
    int minZoom = 30;
    private Map activeMap;

    public GridControl(int width, int height, int xcells, int ycells) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.xcells = xcells;
            this.ycells = ycells;
            cellWidth = width / xcells;
            cellHeight= height/ ycells;
    }

    public GridControl(int width, int height, int cellWidth, int cellHeight, int thisDoesntMatterJustForOverloading) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.cellWidth = cellWidth;
            this.cellHeight = cellHeight;
            xcells = width / cellWidth;
            ycells = height / cellHeight;
    }

    public void drawGrid(Graphics g){
            for(int i = 0; i < xcells; i++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii <ycells; ii++){
                            g.drawRect(i * cellWidth, ii * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight);
                    }
            }
    }

    public int getCellSize() {
            return cellWidth;
    }

    public void editCellSize(int i) {
            if(i == 0)return;
            System.out.println("Resizing: " + i);
            //Pokud je i menší jak 0 -> člověk se pokouší přibližovat
            if(i < 0 && xcells > maxZoom)return;
            if(i > 0 && xcells < minZoom)return;
            this.cellWidth += i;
            this.cellHeight += i;
            xcells = width / cellWidth;
            ycells = height / cellHeight;
    }

    public void setActiveMap(Map map){
            this.activeMap = map;
    }

    public void drawMap(Graphics g, Canvas canvas){
            if(activeMap != null){
                    for(int i = 0; i < xcells; i++){
                            for(int ii = 0; ii <ycells; ii++){
                                    drawRotated(activeMap.getTiles()[i][ii].getTexture(),activeMap.getTiles()[i][ii].getDegrees(), i*cellWidth, ii*cellWidth,canvas, g, null);
                                    //ImageObserver observer = null;
                                    //g.drawImage(activeMap.getTiles()[i][ii].getTexture(), i*cellWidth, ii*cellWidth, observer);
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    public Tile getTileByCoordinate(int x, int y){
            int cellx = x / this.cellWidth;
            int celly = y / this.cellHeight;
            return activeMap.getTiles()[cellx][celly];
    }

    public boolean isWalkable(int x, int y){
            return getTileByCoordinate(x,y).getWalkable();
    }

    public void drawRotated(BufferedImage img,double rotationRequired,int x,int y,Canvas canvas, Graphics g, Observer observer){
            //double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians(degrees);
            double locationX = img.getWidth() / 2;
            double locationY = img.getHeight() / 2;
            AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
            AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

            // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
            g.drawImage(op.filter(img, null), x, y, null);
    }}
```

My Tile method:

```
public class Tile {

    boolean walkable;
    BufferedImage image;
    double radians;
    int ID; //0 - floor, 1 - wall

    public Tile(boolean walkable, BufferedImage image, int ID) {
            this.walkable = walkable;
            this.image = image;
            this.ID = ID;
    }

    public BufferedImage getTexture() {
            return image;
    }

    public boolean getWalkable() {
            return walkable;
    }

    public int getDegrees() {
            return (int) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }

    public int getID() {
            return ID;
    }

    public void setTexture(BufferedImage image, int degrees) {
            this.image = image;
            this.radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
    }
}
```

And my Map creator: (the rotating part is broken, I'll fix that later, now I need to solve my 6-FPS problem)

```
package cs.meowxiik.universes.map;

import cs.meowxiik.universes.graphics.GraphicsManager;


public class MapCreator {

    GraphicsManager graphics;

    public MapCreator(GraphicsManager graphics) {
            this.graphics = graphics;
    }

    public Map getSpaceStationMap(){
            Map map;
            int x = 32;
            int y = 18;
            Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[x][y];
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii < y; ii++){
                            tiles[i][ii] = new Tile(true, graphics.floor, 0);
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii < y; ii++){
                            if(i == 0 || ii == 0 || i == x-1 || ii == y-1)tiles[i][ii] = new Tile(false,graphics.stWallZero, 1); //tiles.get(i).set(ii, new Tile(false,graphics.wall));
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
                    for(int ii = 0; ii < y; ii++){
                            if(tiles[i][ii].getID() == 0)break;
                            boolean connectedUp = false;
                            boolean connectedLeft = false;
                            boolean connectedRight = false;
                            boolean connectedBottom = false;
                            if(i + 1 < tiles.length)
                                    if(tiles[i + 1][ii + 0].getID() == 1)
                                            connectedRight = true;
                            if(i != 0)                                     
                                    if(tiles[i - 1][ii + 0].getID() == 1)
                                            connectedLeft = true;
                            if(ii + 1 < tiles[i].length)
                                    if(tiles[i + 0][ii + 1].getID() == 1)
                                            connectedBottom = true;
                            if(ii != 0)                                    
                                    if(tiles[i + 0][ii - 1].getID() == 1)
                                            connectedUp = true;

                            if(connectedUp && !(connectedLeft || connectedRight || connectedBottom))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallOne, 0);
                            if(connectedLeft && !(connectedUp || connectedRight || connectedBottom))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallOne, 90);
                            if(connectedRight && !(connectedUp || connectedLeft || connectedBottom))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallOne, 180);
                            if(connectedBottom && !(connectedUp || connectedRight || connectedLeft))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallOne, 270);

                            if((connectedUp && connectedBottom) && !(connectedLeft || connectedRight))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallTwo, 90);
                            if(!(connectedUp && connectedBottom) && !(connectedLeft || connectedRight))tiles[i][ii].setTexture(graphics.stWallTwo, 0);
                    }
            }

            map = new Map(x,y,tiles);
            return map;
    }
```

}

Comment: Sure you can. Got some code to help us help you?

Comment: Sure, I can,there is my Tile class:
[Tile](http://pastebin.com/8ggyk2rA). There is my Grid Control (basically drawing class)
[GridControl](http://pastebin.com/GcbXzvX9)
There's a plenty of unimportant code, I have problems with "drawRotated" method and there is my Map creator class: (the part, where is the rotating happening is not working, I know, I will fix that later)
[MapCreator](http://pastebin.com/w7NeeH81)

Comment: Would be a lot better if you could put the code in-line with you question, using links is not the practise here at SO.

Comment: @BrettWalker Ok, I didn't wanted to add loads of code, I though it was unnecessary when I need only a simple method to rotate a BufferedImage itself but if you like examples, then there you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this code

```
  public void drawRotated(BufferedImage img,double rotationRequired,int x,int y,Canvas canvas, Graphics g, Observer observer) {
        //double rotationRequired = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        double locationX = img.getWidth() / 2;
        double locationY = img.getHeight() / 2;
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotationRequired, locationX, locationY);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

        BufferedImage rotatedImage = op.filter(img, null); // my edit here

        // Drawing the rotated image at the required drawing locations
        g.drawImage(rotatedImage , x, y, null);
    }
```

The rotation of the image to get `rotatedImage` is only dependant upon it's size (width/height) and the required rotation.

From my reading of your code the required rotation is largely fixed. The rotation is known when the `setTexture` method of `Title` is called.

Sine this is the case, `rotatedImage` can be computed in the `setTexture` method. Just create a new attribute that stores the computed rotated image. Don't destroy the original.

If `setTexture` is called as often as `drawRotated` then this won't deliver the performance increase you desire.

Comment: Well, it's not what I exactly was asking for, but it will solve the problem, so thank you :)